# Sharepoint Url preview file problem in Incognito

Tags: sharepoint

I have integrated Salesforce with sharepoint but while using file preview url which is coming in response of file it it not working in incognito mode is there any way to openthat serverRelative Url in incognito mode ?

I dont know what to search in this case and also unable to find the solution after go through the documentation